# Textbox validation error provider is not clearing

Tags: c#, errorprovider

I have to show an icon to the user if the pressed/typed any wrong characters, so i'm using error_provider.

In my case, the error_provider is not disappearing, if it's a valid number in the textbox. What is the misatek here??

```
 string text = t_LongitudeRadTextBox.Text;
bool hasDigit = text.Any(letter => Regex.IsMatch(t_LongitudeRadTextBox.Text, "^[0-9]$"));
// Call SetError or Clear on the ErrorProvider.
if (!hasDigit)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(t_LongitudeRadTextBox, "Needs to contain a digit");
}
else
{
    errorProvider1.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `errorProvider1.Clear();` isn't enough as stated in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.clear.aspx) you need to give it an empty string. Like `SetError(t_LongitudeRadTextBox, "")`

> To clear the error message, call the SetError method and pass in Empty
>   for the String value. This removes the error glyph from the specified
>   Control.

Comment: else
   {
       errorProvider1.Clear();
    errorProvider1.SetError(t_LongitudeRadTextBox, "");
   }  //It works by this way//

Comment: How, what is the reg exp for accepting double, this is "^\d*\.?\d*$" not working.

Comment: That sounds like a new question (You got the error provider one to work, right?)... I'm not down with regex, sorry :-)

Comment: Afaik it is possible, but in most cases it's only necessary with one instance... See here fx http://some-dev.blogspot.dk/2011/02/winform-error-provider-for-multiple.html